# How to prove that $L_1(x)\times L_2(x)\times \dots \times L_z(x)=L_1(L_2(\dots (L_z(x)))$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was going through a paper and I came across the following property. I am not able to prove it.

Let $K$ be a finite field, $K^n$ be a linear space
in the finite field, $L_1 (x), L_2 (x),\cdots, L_z (x)$ be $z$ linearized
polynomials on $K^n$ , then the following equality is true. $$L_1(x)\times L_2(x)\times \dots \times L_z(x)=L_1(L_2(\dots (L_z(x)))$$

Link to the paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338593495_Certificateless_Broadcast_Multisignature_Scheme_Based_on_MPKC

Screenshot for a quick look

[image]

Comment: You might want to include a bunch of definitions: linearized polynomial and how it acts on $K^n$, what $\times$ denotes.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned in the paper. @severin

Comment: If you do not know the answer to Severin Schraven's question, then certainly you will not be able to prove anything, and no reader will be able. But let me make a guess:  A linearized polynomial has only linear terms $a_ix_i$ and $\times$ means the usual product in $K$.

Comment: @Paul Frost: that looks strange, because then how can you define $L_{z-1}(L_z(x))$?

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't think your guess is consistent. From the shape of RHS it seems to me that each $L_i$ must map some set to itself, and my guess is that this set is $K^n$. But then $\times$ has to be defined (as far as I can guess) on pairs of elements of $K^n$ and not $K$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician It is just a guess, but in the formula $x$ seems to be an element of  $K$ - otherwise the RHS does not make sense. Perhaps $L_i(x) = L_i(x,\ldots,x)$?